# Is there a way to improve this Delegate<void(int&)>::Bind<TestStruct&, &TestStruct::somefunction>(testStruct, value) syntax?

Tags: c++, callback, delegates, c++20, non-type-template-parameter

I am trying to implement a Delegate type that would work with generic callbacks and work in presence of an overload set.

For simplification here is an excerpt of the class with the bind method implemented as static function to simplify the problem.

```
template <typename Signature>
class Delegate;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct Delegate<Ret(Args...)> {
    using Trampoline_T = Ret (*)(void*, Args&&...);
    using TrampolineConst_T = Ret (*)(const void*, Args&&...);

    using Function_Sig = Ret(Args...);
    using Function_Ptr = std::add_pointer_t<Function_Sig>;

    template <typename Instance_T>
    using MemberFunction_Sig = Ret(std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>&,
                                   Args...);
    template <typename Instance_T>
    using MemberFunction_Ptr =
        Ret (std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>::*)(Args...);
    template <typename Instance_T>
    using MemberFunctionConst_Ptr =
        Ret (std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>::*)(Args...) const;
    template <typename Instance_T>
    using MemberFunctionConstOrNot_Ptr =
        std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>>,
                           MemberFunctionConst_Ptr<Instance_T>,
                           MemberFunction_Ptr<Instance_T>>;

    template <typename Instance_T, MemberFunctionConstOrNot_Ptr<Instance_T> fct, typename T>
    static void Bind(T&& instance, auto&& value) {

        if constexpr (!std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>>) {
            Trampoline_T trampoline = [](void* storage, Args&&... args) -> Ret {
                std::invoke(
                    fct,
                    *reinterpret_cast<std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>*>(
                        storage),
                    std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
            };
            trampoline(&instance, value);
        } else {
            TrampolineConst_T trampoline = [](const void* storage,
                                              Args&&... args) -> Ret {
                std::invoke(
                    fct,
                    *reinterpret_cast<std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>*>(
                        storage),
                    std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
            };
            trampoline(&instance, value);
        }
    }

    template <typename Instance_T>
    static void Bind(Instance_T&& instance, auto&& value) {
        if constexpr (!std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>>) {
            Trampoline_T trampoline = [](void* storage, Args&&... args) -> Ret {
                std::invoke(
                    *reinterpret_cast<std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>*>(
                        storage),
                    std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
            };
            trampoline(&instance, value);
        } else {
            TrampolineConst_T trampoline = [](const void* storage,
                                              Args&&... args) -> Ret {
                std::invoke(
                    *reinterpret_cast<std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>*>(
                        storage),
                    std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
            };
            trampoline(&instance, value);
        }
    }
};
```

Now to use such a type with an object Test

```
class TestStruct {
   public:
    constexpr static int m_staticValue = 42;
    uint8_t m_value = m_staticValue;

    void somefunctionGeneric(auto& value) {
        std::cout << "somefunctionGeneric " << value << "\n";
    }
    void somefunctionGeneric(auto& value) const {
        std::cout << "somefunctionGeneric const " << value + 1 << "\n";
    }
    void somefunction(int& value) {
        std::cout << "somefunction " << value << "\n";
    }
    void somefunction(int& value) const {
        std::cout << "somefunction const " << value + 1 << "\n";
    }

    void operator()(auto& value) {
        std::cout << "operator()(auto&) " << value << "\n";
    }
    void operator()(auto& value) const {
        std::cout << "operator()(auto&) const " << value + 1 << "\n";
    }
    void operator()(int& value) {
        std::cout << "operator()(int&) " << value << "\n";
    }
    void operator()(int& value) const {
        std::cout << "operator()(int&) const " << value + 1 << "\n";
    }
};
```

You would use it this way:

```
int value = 42;
double valueDouble = 42;
TestStruct testStruct;
Delegate<void(int&)>::Bind<TestStruct&, &TestStruct::somefunction>(testStruct, value);
Delegate<void(double&)>::Bind<TestStruct&,&TestStruct::somefunctionGeneric<double>>(testStruct, valueDouble);

Delegate<void(int&)>::Bind(testStruct, value);
Delegate<void(double&)>::Bind(testStruct, valueDouble);

const TestStruct testStructConst;
Delegate<void(int&)>::Bind<const TestStruct&, &TestStruct::somefunction>(testStructConst, value);
Delegate<void(double&)>::Bind<const TestStruct&, &TestStruct::somefunctionGeneric<double>>(testStructConst, valueDouble);

Delegate<void(int&)>::Bind(testStructConst, value);
Delegate<void(double&)>::Bind(testStructConst, valueDouble);
```

[Compiler explorer code](https://godbolt.org/z/7v7h6MndT)

I would like to improve the Bind call syntax. I have to pass the class and the function as template. I feel like there is some trick to improve that. Like using a class template to deduce the types. It might not be possible and that if know it can't be improved with c++20 I will gladly accept this answer.

Requirements:
The function has to be a template parameter to be captured in the trampoline lambda. The trampoline lambda has to be convertible to function pointer.
It has to work with overload set function like: `void somefunction(int& value)` and `void somefunction(int& value) const`
The function should be able to be a template const or not.
Lambda should be supported.
And please don't suggest std::function, this is what I have is 10% more performant when the function is inlinable.

It works at the moment, but I am pretty shure I saw techniques to improve this `Delegate<void(int&)>::Bind<TestStruct&, &TestStruct::somefunction>(testStruct, value);` I just can't figure them out at the moment.

Thank you very much

Note: Yes the value is passed in the Bind fucntion this is just for ilustration and because the bind function are static. In my code there is a Bind and an invoke function.

Comment: Why are you passing the function arguments to `Bind`? That rather defeats the purpose of delegates.

Comment: @Passer By If you took the time to read the question you would see that it is to simplify the problem. Of course in my real code the function arguments are passed in a separate function, but the class is more complicated since I have to store the target and the trampoline.

Comment: Ah yes, I skipped everything after reading "thank". It's not obvious what you're doing reading from the start. You could skip the class type by inferring the const-ness from the argument I believe.

Comment: @Passer By No problem, it is a long question, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I want to improve this is since the instance type has to be provided by the user it is really error prone. He has to figure out is his instance const or not, a ref or a rvalue ref. When actually all this info is already present when he passes the instance to the bind function.

How I improved it is by using a public internal class. Things can be more improved and names could be better but here is the principle and how it is used.

```
template <typename Signature>
class Delegate;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct Delegate<Ret(Args...)> {
    /* previous code from the question */

    // Don't mind the Trampoline type they are for the question in my real code this is a type ereased type.
    template <typename Instance_T, MemberFunctionConstOrNot_Ptr<Instance_T> fct>
    inline static Trampoline_T trampolineLambda = [](void* storage, Args&&... args) -> void {
        std::invoke(fct, *reinterpret_cast<std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>*>(storage), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };

    template <typename Instance_T, MemberFunctionConstOrNot_Ptr<Instance_T> fct>
    inline static TrampolineConst_T trampolineLambdaConst = [](const void* storage, Args&&... args) -> void {
        std::invoke(fct, *reinterpret_cast<std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>*>(storage), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };

    template <typename Instance_T>
    struct MemFnBinder
    {
        Delegate<Ret(Args...)>* m_delegate;

        Instance_T m_intance;

        template <MemberFunctionConstOrNot_Ptr<Instance_T> fct>
        void Bind()
        {
            using Type = std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>;

            // Don't mind the fact that I am dealing with the constness like this. 
            // It is a by product of simplifying the code for the question. 
            constexpr bool IsConst = std::is_const_v<Type>;
            if constexpr (not IsConst) {
                m_delegate->m_trampoline = trampolineLambda<Instance_T, fct>;
            } else {
                m_delegate->m_trampolineConst = trampolineLambdaConst<Instance_T, fct>;
            }
        }
    };

    template <typename Instance_T>
    decltype(auto) GetMemFnBinder(Instance_T&& instance)
    {
        return MemFnBinder<Instance_T>{this, instance};
    }
};
```

How it is used, using the same TestStruct from the question. Disregards also that I am creating `Delegate<void(int&)>{}` temporaries it is just I couldn't make the function `GetMemFnBinder` static because of how I did the **trampolines**. It is inconsequential for the design pattern.

```
TestStruct testStruct;
const TestStruct testStructConst;
Delegate<void(int&)> delegate{};
delegate.GetMemFnBinder(testStruct).Bind<&TestStruct::somefunction>(); 
delegate.GetMemFnBinder(testStructConst).Bind<&TestStruct::somefunction>();
delegate.GetMemFnBinder(std::move(testStructConst)).Bind<&TestStruct::somefunction>();
delegate.GetMemFnBinder(TestStruct{}).Bind<&TestStruct::somefunction>();
```

I believe this is better than

```
Delegate<void(int&)>::Bind<TestStruct&, &TestStruct::somefunction>(testStruct);
Delegate<void(int&)>::Bind<const TestStruct&, &TestStruct::somefunction>(testStructConst);
Delegate<void(int&)>::Bind<TestStruct&&, &TestStruct::somefunction>(TestStruct{});
```

I agree that the name that I choose can be improved. I'll find better names when my brain is rested.